# php-fpm environment variable not working

Tags: php, nginx, environment-variables

I have the following inside /etc/php-fpm-7.1.d/www.conf:

```
env[MYVAR] = $HOSTNAME
env[MYVAR2] = hello
```

After restarting php-fpm and nginx, I load my website and type the two variables.. I get nothing for the first, but "hello" for the second. Any idea why? According to the docs ("all $VARIABLEs are taken from
; the current environment."), it's supposed to work and $HOSTNAME does contain a valid value when 'echo'ed from shell...

Comment: Have you uncommented the `;clear_env = no` option in your config?

Comment: yes I have. I also tried not specifying env[xxx] = yyyy at all, assuming "clear_env = no" will auto-import all variables. Worth mentioning the variables are set via docker run -e xxx=yyy and are visible later in root's shell.

Comment: You might want to check  `variables_order` option in php.ini. Environment variables only work if it is set to `EGPCS`.

Comment: it is set to EGPCS. I also tried GPCS. No change.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I am encountering a similar issue - svery frustrating

Comment: nah, I eventually had some wrapping environment setup script push those values into php.ini programatically..

Comment: Are you using systemd? I found I needed to add Environment="HOSTNAME=%H" to the appropriate php-fpm.service file, in addition to modifying php-fpm/www.conf and php.ini's variables_order. All three were required.